# Start session on the site using OpenID

Tags: php, single-sign-on, owncloud

I have an instance of [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) (its in PHP) installed on my machine. I have also setup an openID server using [SimpleID](http://simpleid.koinic.net/) (this is in PHP) saparately on my machine. I would like to intgrate the two so that once I log in to my ownCloud a session is started at my OpenID server as well without entering uername and password again. How can this be accomplished? I followed various methods including cURL but none of them worked for me. I am thankful to any help regarding this.

**UPDATE**

If an example can be given even without specifically for ownCloud and SimpleID it is very helpful.

Comment: did u try rouncube : roundcub4OC? https://github.com/hypery2k/owncloud/issues/153